# Ruby, What makes letters greater than another or what gives letters values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables

So I've been experimenting with this particular problem.
I'm creating a method that determines if the vowels of a word are in the correct order. Example: "Apple" works but "Utah" doesn't. "a" comes before "e" but "u" doesn't come before "a"

Here is my method:

```
  def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  letters_array = word.split("")

  vowels_array = letters_array.select { |char| vowels.include?(char)}
  (0..vowels_array.length - 2).all? do |a|
  vowels_array[a] <= vowels_array[a + 1]
  end
end
```

It works.  The only line I'm confused about is the last line, why am I able to have a vowel greater than another vowel?  How can a letter be greater than or less than another letter unless I reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters in my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two strings using > (greater than sign) in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618216/comparing-two-strings-using-greater-than-sign-in-ruby)

Comment: @samsymons I don't think this is a duplicate of the referenced question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is safe to assume that Ruby is indeed comparing the ASCII code values, albeit behind the scenes.
To get an ASCII code you can use

```
   'a'[0].ord
=> 97
```

The ASCII code for "Z" is 90, the code for "A" is 65, and the code for "[" is 91.

Note the output for the following comparisons:

```
  'A' < 'z' ## capital letters before lowercase
=> true

  'Z' < 'a' ## capital letters before lowercase
=> true

   '[' < 'a' ## [ \ ] ^ _ ` nested between capital and lowercase letters
=> true

   '[' < 'Z' ## [ \ ] ^ _ ` nested between capital and lowercase letters
=> false
```

In particular, the comparison of letters with these 6 symbols ([ \ ] ^ _ `) that have ASCII codes in between the capital and lowercase letters provides fairly convincing evidence of the way Ruby makes comparisons between letters (and, more generally, strings).

Answer (score 1):

It probably compares the ASCII values of both characters. For example:

```
"a" < "b" is True
"K" < "Z" is True
"c" < "b" is False
```